# Microsoft ODBC error after building Java program

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, odbc, dsn

I made a little Java application which writes stuff to an Access database.
When I run it in Eclipse, it works just fine, but when i build it using Maven and run it, it fails.
As soon as I try to access the database it gives me the following error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Manager] Data source
>   name not found and no default driver
>   specified

I know this is a common error but there are so many vague solutions out there I'm too confused to get it fixed.

I have no User DSN's or System DSN's whatsoever, I also don't have a running SQL server as far as I know.

I have no clue as to what to do next.

Comment: Well, do you have an ODBC connect string for your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wondering if this could be a bitness issue (assuming the machine is 64bit)?

I suspect that this is more about which Java Runtime Environment) is being used to execute the built application rather than what is used to actually build it...

Microsoft only has a 32bit ODBC driver for Access - so, unless the Java application is being run in a 32bit JRE then I suspect there will be no way it can interface with the 32bit native C portion of the Bridge that, in turn, will load the 32bit ODBC Driver.

Just a thought...

Comment: U were correct, I found out to late though. Thanks for the help anyway ;)

Comment: For 64-bit goodness, you should be able to use the 64-bit version of the ACE, which is downloadable and redistributable. It is backwardly compatible with older file formats (MDB), not just limited to the new ACCDB format.

Answer (score 0):

You probably use connect string with relative `.mdb` filename. You can use full filename:

```
jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=c:\\Nwind.mdb
```